# What is RxJS (redux-observable) alternative to takeLatest from redux-saga?

Tags: rxjs, redux-saga, redux-observable

If new action is received by epic, stop processing old action(s).
A little bit of context: I have an epic, that emits few delayed actions.
I need to cancel them, if new action is received by epic.

Redux-saga effect that does exactly what I want:
[takeLatest](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/index.html#takelatestpattern-saga-args)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's exactly what [.switchMap](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/file/es6/operator/switchMap.js.html) operator does:

> Projects each source value to an Observable which is merged in the output
>   Observable, emitting values only from the most recently projected Observable.

In this example you can see that previous `interval` is no longer processing after new `click` arrives:

```js
const clicks = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click');
const result = clicks.switchMap((ev) => Rx.Observable.interval(1000));

result.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
<button>send new click</button>
```